# Seeking insights on account abstraction from experienced developers

Tags: smart-contract-wallets

I am conducting research on the topic of account abstraction and was wondering if anyone here has experience working with this concept in their projects. I am particularly interested in hearing from developers who have firsthand experience with account abstraction and could share their insights and perspectives on the topic.

These days, we see a lot of projects building SDKs to implement Smart Contract Wallet + infra (bundler+mempool) for Dapps. I've received some feedback from developers, with some saying they can build these components in-house and others saying they need to rely on an SDK. I would love to hear your thoughts on this issue.

If you have any insights or experiences you could share on account abstraction, I would really appreciate it. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: we (experienced developers) never heard of this thing "account abstraction", so you might want to explain to us what kind of knowledge you want to get about accounts

Comment: @Nulik I am talking about EIP-4337, which was co-written by Vitalik. Here is a link to it: [link](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337). Instead of relying on Externally Owned Accounts, such as Metamask, we can rely on Smart Contract Wallets. Account abstraction is the process of making it easier for users to interact with the blockchain by customizing certain elements of smart contract accounts, such as fee payment methods and transaction approval mechanisms.

Comment: ok. so, when was this thing included in current `go-ethereum` source code ? I can't find any function named "handleOps()" there (this function name is specified in your link) Or maybe it is in some development branch of github repository???

Comment: @nulik - Unfortunately, EIP-4337 has not been implemented yet. However, some projects are starting to consider it.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the usage of handleOps() in the original ERC-4337 specification. This link should help: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-4337#extension-paymasters.

the handleOps call contains the packaged multiple UserOperation objects from a bundle transaction. This call is made to a golbal entry point contract that is pre-published.

Answer (score 0):

ERC-4337(Its not an EIP i.e it is operating at the application level and not consensus level) has only been implemented into Ethereum Mainet from March 2023. Most Web3 developers are slowly coming to terms with it since Ethereum has focused on the merge. This is despite the fact that ERC-4337 was initially proposed in 2015. Awareness is slowly increasing and recent ETH events have featured presentations or workshops on the AA (Account abstraction)